# Stop click propagation from Ember action?

Tags: javascript, view, ember.js, click

I have this code that when icon-edit span is clicked, it fires an action that opens a modal, however, at the same time, the click propagates to the view below it (personView). I want the action to execute and stop the propagation.

The only solution I can think of is to make the icon-edit its own view and stop the click propagation by returning false in method click. Is there any other way of doing this without making another view?

HBS:

```
{{#view Blocks.PersonView}}
  <span class="inline pull-right icon-edit" {{action 'modalOpen' 'modifyPersonPopup' 'modifyPerson' this}}></span>
  <p class="inline pull-left person-name">{{firstNameDelayed}}</p>
{{/view}}
```

Comment: Is there a click event hook already called in PersonView and are you handling a click inside the modalOpen action?

Comment: There's a click event hook inside person view

Comment: One option is to look at the event.target in PersonView and if the target is .icon-edit, use the Em.ViewtargetActionSupport mixin to call the action modalOpen. But that's still a bit hacky. You may need to use event.preventDefault(); and event.stopPropagation(); together too.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Also you can add `bubbles=false` parameter to `action` tag. See the [API documentation](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/action?anchor=action) for how to configure event propagation.

Comment: This is a much better answer that I had originally I selected. Just switched this to be the accepted answer!

Comment: Awesome ! This exactly what I was looking for. BTW the link related to ember doc doesn't mention anything on bubbles.

Comment: Most likely this is no more valid for Ember 2.x (you are automatically redirected to 2.x guide section by the link above) since this item is still present for Ember 1.x docs.

Comment: Actually this worked for me with Ember 2.5. I just added bubbles=false after my last parameter in the action definition in my template.

Answer (score 6):

Try to modify the action:

```
modalOpen: function {
    //code of your action
    return false;    
}
```

This worked for me in a similar situation

Comment: Tnx, bubble=false did not help but this yes.

Comment: Hopefully you tried `bubbles=false` which works exactly as `return false;` works in the action.

Comment: Bubbles=false doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

The octane way of achieving this would be using the `stop-propagation` helper from the [ember-event-helpers](https://github.com/buschtoens/ember-event-helpers) addon.

```
<span class="inline pull-right icon-edit" {{on "click" (stop-propagation (queue this.modalOpen this.modifyPersonPopup this.modifyPerson))}}></span>
```