# Disable/Prevent PhotoSwipe Launch on Anchor Click

Tags: javascript, closures, photoswipe, flickity

It's a [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co) carousel which contains images that open in [PhotoSwipe](https://photoswipe.com).

There are `a` tags within the Flickity Slides which "work", but the PhotoSwipe modal flashes prior to the `window.location` changing (default HTML click).

I need some kind of test before running `openPhotoSwipe()` and had tried the following, but it (of course) only works on the second click:

```
$gallery.dataset = [];  
$gallery.dataset.linkClicked = false;

$('.project-archive-link').on('click', function() {
    $gallery.dataset.linkClicked = true;
});
$gallery.on('staticClick.flickity', function(event, pointer, cellElement, cellIndex) {
    if (!cellElement) {
      return;
    }

// Photoswipe functions
var openPhotoSwipe = function() {

...

if ($gallery.dataset.linkClicked === false ) {
    openPhotoSwipe();
}
```

This is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/MikeiLL/pen/REeZgG) with the basic framework.

I'm betting my approach is wrong.

Comment: I think that _maybe_ I need to rethink the Event Listeners as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32702560/2223106

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developed a [working solution](https://codepen.io/MikeiLL/pen/qLMEBE) (not extensively tested) based on [this recommendation](https://github.com/metafizzy/flickity/issues/685#issuecomment-362671850) by [David DeSandro](https://github.com/desandro), flickity's developer, with further input from [this Flickity issue](https://github.com/metafizzy/flickity/issues/81#issue-60874720) to replace `cellIndex` with the cell index as obtained by `jQuery`.

The Flickity event listener is bound to the `img` tags within the `$gallery`. Then the `index` of the `parent` of the target is used as the Photoswipe image within it's `options` array.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


// Flickity
  // --------- /
  var $gallery = $('.gallery').flickity({
    imagesLoaded: true,
    percentPosition: false,
    wrapAround: true,
    pageDots: true
  });
  var flkty = $gallery.data('flickity');

  $gallery.on('click', 'img', function(e) {
     var index = $(e.target).parent().index();

    // Photoswipe functions
    var openPhotoSwipe = function() {
      var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0];

      // build items array

      var items = $.map($(".gallery").find("img"), function(el) {
        return {          
          "src": el.getAttribute('data-src'),
          "w":   el.width,
          "h":   el.height
        }
      });

      var options = {  
        history: false,
        index: index
      };

      var gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
      gallery.init();
    };

    openPhotoSwipe();
  });


});
```