# How can I prevent an action on a parent component from being called when I click on a child component?

Tags: ember.js

I have the following bit of template in a project I'm working on:

```
<div class="item row" {{action "expandItem"}}>
  {{input type="checkbox" checked=isChecked}}
  {{item.name}}
</div>
```

The trouble I'm running into is that clicking the checkbox does not change its state.  It does, however, fire the `expandItem` action.  I'd like the behavior to be that clicking on the checkbox changes `isChecked` but clicking anywhere else in the div fires `expandItem`.  How can I accomplish this?

EDIT: The question [Stop click propagation from Ember action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230430/stop-click-propagation-from-ember-action) is very close, but the difference as I see it is that the child element in the other question is using the {{action}} helper, which can easily stop propagation with bubbles=false. In my case, I don't necessarily have a hook into how Ember's default Input Component bubbles the action

SECOND EDIT: I recreated exactly the behavior I'm seeing in [this JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/keyupohuqo/edit?html,css,js,output).  You'll notice how the Input Component and the inline `action` helper behave differently.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop click propagation from Ember action?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230430/stop-click-propagation-from-ember-action)

Comment: @DeepakJose - it is very close, the difference as I see it is that the child element in the other question is using the `{{action}}` helper, which can easily stop propagation with `bubbles=false`.  In my case, I don't necessarily have a hook into how Ember's default Input Component bubbles the action.

Comment: try `{{input type="checkbox" checked=isChecked bubbles=false}}`

Comment: @locks, just tried...no change

Answer (score 4):

Since Ember 1.13.3 you can do the following (the example does not use input helper and I would not recommend using it if possible):

*Template:*

```
<label onclick={{action "stopPropagation"}}>
    <input type="checkbox" checked={{checked}} 
           onchange={{action "check" value="target.checked"}}>
</label>
```

*Component/controller:*

```
actions: {
   check() {
      this.toggleProperty('checked');    
   },
   stopPropagation(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
   }
}
```

You cannot just stop action from propagating with `bubbles=false` since in this case `event.preventDefault` is also called disabling default checkbox behavour.

Here is [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/7c36c3c8f48e487f80cfd1406352deb5)

Answer (score 0):

I was intrigued by this problem, as far as I see there is no native way to prevent bubbling the event from an input helper.

But there is a workaround. Create a non visible div floating above the checkbox, and use a click event that selects the underlying checkbox:

*Template*:

```
<div class="item row" {{action "expandItem"}}>
  <div style="position-absolute; display: inline-block;">
    <div {{action "toggleSelect" bubbles=false}} style="position: absolute;left: 0;width: 12px;top: 0;bottom: 0;"></div>
    {{input type="checkbox" checked=isChecked}}
  </div>
  {{item.name}}
</div>
```

*Action in Controller/Component*:

```
actions: {
  toggleSelect() {
    this.set('isChecked', !this.get('isChecked'));
  }
}
```